# npx expo-cli install error, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, proxy

I'm in proxy network and im trying to start new react native project using *npx expo-cli init* but I got this error message:

```
Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template.
request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank/-/expo-template-blank-45.0.3.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
```

I have set my proxy network inside npm and remove the strict-ssl config using this syntax:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

npm config set proxy http://(myProxyAddress):(myPort)
npm config set https-proxy http://(myProxyAddress):(myPort)
```

Im able to surf through internet, running expo by npm start, but i can't start a new project.

Im also unable to ping 8.8.8.8 by proxy network, but able if using non-proxy network.

If im not using proxy network, im able to start a new project by *npx expo-cli init*

What am I missing? Any respone would be appreciated!

Comment: You have to love software that uses such precise error messages as "something went wrong"...  In any case the *next* line says that the name resolution failed. What name server are you pointing to and can you reach it? (8.8.8.8 is one of Google's public name servers.)

Comment: Hey thank you for reaching me out, i want to access npmjs.org and it failed, i tried to ping google and it also failed. But im already resolved this issue in this question's answer. It turns out that it needs to be added '--npm' in the end of the syntax. Also for the timed out ping, looks like i need to configure proxy for my git also. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

npx expo-cli init title is already deprecated for now. Instead, you could use this code to start a new project for react native:

```
npx expo-cli init projectTitle --npm
```